# python code to get values from json data

Tags: python, json

Am trying to extract command line arguments passed in python

```
cmdargs = str(sys.argv)
print cmdargs
```

it prints

```
['E:/omation.py', '{"command":"sel_media","value":"5X7_phot
o_paper.png"},{"command":"tray","value":"4X6_photo_paper.png"}']
```

from this how can i extract `command` and `values` .
i dont knoe how to loop this array and get the commnd and value values.plese help
Note: i also want to discard the first value  `'E:/omation.py'`

Comment: Is that exactly what it prints? Cause looks like there is a missing quote.

Comment: That is not valid JSON. How about passing the two objects as separate arguments?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python utils to parse json strings:

```
import json
examples = json.loads('['+cmdargs[1]+']')
```

The first import loads json utilities for python. Then, you can parse a json string into a Python dictionary by using `json.loads`. In the example, I have parsed one of your json strings into a python dictionary. Remember to add '[' and ']' to convert your string to a valid json array. Then, you can get a command and a value like :

```
print(examples[0]['command'])
print(examples[0]['value' ])
```

Comment: This will not work because the input is not valid JSON.

Comment: Solved. According to its format, he would only need to convert it to an array. He can add the '[' and ']' and make it a json array

Answer (score 1):

Your input is not valid JSON. You must find a way to pass the arguments as separate, valid JSON objects. Then you can do this:

```
# j.py
import json
import sys

print(sys.argv)
for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
    j = json.loads(arg)
    print(j.get("command"))
    print(j.get("value"))
```

Usage could be:

```
$ python3 j.py '{"command":"sel_media","value":"5X7_photo_paper.png"}' '{"command":"tray","value":"4X6_photo_paper.png"}'
['j.py', '{"command":"sel_media","value":"5X7_photo_paper.png"}', '{"command":"tray","value":"4X6_photo_paper.png"}']
sel_media
5X7_photo_paper.png
tray
4X6_photo_paper.png
```

Comment: but one problem is am using `import simplejson as json` not usinh josn

Comment: it prints `print(sys.argv)` value only after that nothing getting

Comment: How do you pass the arguments? Take a close look, I use *two* arguments.

Comment: i also use two arguments. same arguments u uded

Comment: it is my code `import sys
sys.path.append('C:\ProgramData\SikuliX\Lib\simplejson-3.3.3' )
import os
import simplejson as json
print(sys.argv)
for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
    j = json.loads(arg)
 
    print(j.get("command"))
    print(j.get("value"))`

Comment: PLease edit your question, don't put code into comments. It is very hard to read.

Comment: helllo one issue is here is the printed data `print(sys.argv)` prints  `['E:/automation.sikuli/automation.py', '{"command":"sel_media","value":"5X7_phot
o_paper.png"},{"command":"sel_printer","value":"4X6_photo_paper.png"}']`

Comment: it is my sys.args[1]`'{"command":"sel_media","value":"5X7_phot o_paper.png"},{"command":"sel_printer","value":"4X6_photo_paper.png"}'` how can i put seperate single quotes in each values

Comment: So you did *not* pass the JSON as *two* arguments but as *one*. You have two options: 1) pass *two* arguments and use my code, 2) pass *one* argument and use one of the other answers.

Comment: can u please modify ur answer like that so that i can acceprt ur anser

Comment: My question? *You* asked, it is your question. I only tried to answer.

Comment: but passing two argument like  `'{"command":"sel_media","value":"5X7_phot o_paper.png"},{"command":"sel_printer","value":"4X6_photo_paper.png"}'`  it is not working

Comment: That is *one* argument because it is enclosed in `'...'`. Split it into *two* arguments, each enclosed in `'...'`.

Answer (score 1):

The example you give shows two json objects in the second element of the list cmdargs.  Probably the easiest way to capture that case would be to enclose that second argument in square braces, which would make it legal JSON, then loop through the resulting list:

```
import json
a = json.loads('['+cmdargs[1]+']')

for p in a:
    print "command is ", p['command']
    print "value is ", p['value']
```

This is specific to the example you showed, you may need to make it more robust for your purposes.